# Does brevity refer to speech and writing or the content itself?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I’m unsure whether using the word brevity in my context is correct. Essentially in the foreword of a document I want to say that the document itself only contains the necessary parts/topics rather than including every trivial piece of information. In this context, would it be correct to say that ‘I have placed emphasis on brevity’, or does brevity only refer to writing and speech itself rather than the content?

If not, what clearer and concise approach could be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you look carefully at the definition of ***brevity***, you will see that it does refer to content, too, in the sense that content is expressed into words. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brevity) defines *brevity*

> especially : shortness or ***conciseness of expression***

However, if you try to characterise *a document*, I think a ***brief document*** does not really refer to lack of redundant details. I would rather say this is *a concise document*. So I think that

> I have placed emphasis on *conciseness*

is more recommended.

The same dictionary, [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concise#:%7E:text=concise%2C%20terse%2C%20succinct%2C%20laconic,description%20terse%20implies%20pointed%20conciseness.), shows that conciseness is more accurate here, as it means:

> marked by brevity of expression or statement : ***free from all elaboration and superfluous detail***
>
> - a concise report

Comment: I like this response, but disagree that a "brief document" is unusual.  A brief document is just a short document, but has no connotation of conciseness, precision, or care.  If you say I'm going to give some brief remarks, you mean you will not say a lot, but are not otherwise characterizing the content.  A concise document means the document will choose the most economical means of expressing only what needs to be expressed.

Comment: @Vegawatcher Indeed, I checked GNgrams and you are right. I guess I felt it strange in expressing the OP's meaning, but it is not uncommon in general, meaning short document. I have edited.